# Перебрать json-массив внутри json-массива

Tags: javascript

Есть json-массив:

```
let arr = [{
    "country": "Russia",
    "city": "Moscow",
    "airports": [
        {
            "name": "Smeremetyevo",
            "iata": "SVO"
        },
        {
            "name": "Vnukovo",
            "iata": "VKO"
        },
        {
            "name": "Domodedovo",
            "iata": "DME"
        },
        {
            "name": "Zhukovskiy",
            "iata": "ZIA"
        }
    ]
},{
    "country": "Ukraine",
    "city": "Kiev",
    "airports": [
        {
            "name": "Boryspil",
            "iata": "KBP"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kiev",
            "iata": "IEV"
        }
    ]  
}];
```

Хочу вывести на экран строку с каждый аэропортом так, чтобы проходя один цикл массива он забирал по одному аэропорту.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $('#list').append('<p>' + 
        arr[i].country + 
        ', ' + 
        arr[i].city + 
        ': <span style="font-weight: bold">' +
        arr[i].airports[i].name + 
        '</span></p>');
}
```

Получается, что выводится только первый элемент из списка, но, в итоге, должно получится так:

- Russia, Moscow: **Sheremetyevo**
- Russia, Moscow: **Vnukovo**
- Russia, Moscow: **Domodedovo**
- Russia, Moscow: **Zhukovskiy**

  Как мне реализовать нужный мне вывод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если массив массивов, наверное, должно быть два цикла?

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].airports.length; j++) {
    $('#list').append('<p>' + 
        arr[i].country + 
        ', ' + 
        arr[i].city + 
        ': <span style="font-weight: bold">' +
        arr[i].airports[j].name + 
        '</span></p>');
  }
}
```